# Elastic APM does not track http-transactions

Tags: php, apm, elastic-apm

APM client for PHP does not track HTTP transactions.
In the view, I see only `cli` transaction type.
Also, other services which call this service does recognize this service as external.

APM version: 1.7.1
PHP version: 8.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to APM version `1.7.1`.
Probably [1.7.2](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-php/pull/857) have fixed integration with fpm or something

I have updated to `1.8.1` and integration start to work correctly.